# How to disable connection pooling in Webclient in Springboot 2.6.2?

Tags: spring-webclient

How to disable connection pooling in Webclient in Springboot 2.6.2?

Below is my sample codes.
Is it right?
(WebClientBuilder is been using as singleton.)

```
public class WebClientBuilder {
    private static WebClient webClient;

    public static WebClient getWebClient() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("getWebClient");

        if (webClient != null) {
            LOGGER.debug("webClient exist");
            return webClient;
        }

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().newConnection()
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        ReactorClientHttpConnector reactorClientHttpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

        LOGGER.debug("webClient was generated");

        webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(reactorClientHttpConnector).build();
        
        return webClient;
    }
}
```

The webClient instance is been using like below code,

```
...
return WebClientBuilder
                    .getWebClient()
                    .post()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do it but you can control the number of connections in pool using `ConnectionProvider.maxConnections`

```
ConnectionProvider provider = ConnectionProvider.builder("http")
        .maxConnections(1)
        .build();

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(provider);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .build();
```